# PyQt + shortcut to trigger a button

Tags: python, button, keyboard-shortcuts, pyqt

How do I configure keyboard shortcuts to click specific buttons in a PyQT app? Eg: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to click one button while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to click the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [QtGui.QShortcut](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qshortcut.html): you build it with a `QKeySequence`, and it emits the `activated()` signal when that key sequence is typed while the shortcut's parent widget has focus (of course, you connect those signals to slots of your choosing, including buttons').

Comment: Broken link. For PyQt5 the class was moved to [PyQt5.QtWidgets.QShortcut](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/QtWidgets/qshortcut.html?highlight=shortcut##PyQt5-QtWidgets-QShortcut)