# Qt 5.4 Ctrl+Z shortcut conflict in Python? Doesn't work until its button has been pressed

Tags: python, qt, keyboard-shortcuts

In Qt Designer 5.4, I have a QPushButton and have set its shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.  I'm using pyuic5 to turn it into Python code.  This is the resulting line in the Python code:

```
self.quickTextUndoButton.setShortcut(_translate("newEntryDialog", "Ctrl+Z"))
```

When running the application, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> does not call the slot as expected, until the QPushButton has been pressed (which does call the slot); thereafter, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> DOES call the slot as expected.

This 'initializing' behavior does not happen with other buttons with shortcuts <kbd>F1</kbd> thru <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Is this a conflict with the existing interpretation of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>?  If so, is there an easy way to avoid that conflict?  Maybe just setting the ShortcutContext appropriately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking on the button will give it the keyboard focus, and, more importantly, remove focus from any other widget which has the same shortcut set.

All of the editable input widgets (such as `QLineEdit`, `QTextEdit`, etc) have hard-coded [default key bindings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#details) for various actions, including <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> (which undoes the last action). If such a widget has the keyboard focus, its shortcut will get priority over the one you set for the button (and vice versa).

When more than one widget has the same shortcut, you can set an event-filter and use `ShortcutOverride` to disambiguate them:

```
    self.lineEdit.installEventFilter(self)
    ...

def eventFilter(self, source, event):
    if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ShortcutOverride and
        event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier and
        event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Z):
        # eat the shortcut on the line-edit
        return True
    return super(Window, self).eventFilter(source, event)
```

However, as a user, I really **hate** applications that do this kind of thing. When I use a standard input widget, I expect to be able to use all the standard keyboard bindings. If they don't work as expected, it just looks like a bug.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a shot soon.  Figured it was something like that.  I generally agree: reusing the universally-known shortcuts is not a step to be taken lightly.  Without full context, I would hate the idea too.

Comment: Yup that was the ticket of course.  If I understand eventFilters correctly, then what I'm doing should be robust: I added the event filter you show to the top level application, to always return true for Ctrl-Z, since there is actually nowhere in the application that I want Ctrl-Z to have its default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> Try **QKeySequence**

For example;

```
ctrl_z = "Ctrl+Z"
key_seq = QtGui.QKeySequence(ctrl_z)
btn.setShortcut(key_seq)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, however, I tried your code as closely as possible, with the same results.  I was also curious about where the "Ctrl+Z" gets turned in to a QKeySequence, but, one of the functions apparently does it automatically.  You can do things like btn.setShortcut("F1") and they do get correctly registered just as if you had done btn.setShortcut(Qt.Key_F1) - but I haven't looked enough to find where in the docs that conversion happens.  So - btn.setShortcut("Ctrl+Z") DOES work, AFTER its button has been pressed once to 'initialize' it.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039241/pyqt-shortcut-to-trigger-a-button

Comment: That post doesn't seem to have any relevant detail.  Maybe the problem is not being communicated clearly.  The shortcut does work as expected, but only after its button is clicked once.  I suspect the button click is needed to give it higher priority than the default Ctrl+Z functionality in the parent widget, or something like that.